# How to install Chrome extension through windows registry in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions

Used the following tutorial:

> Using the Windows registry
>
> 1. Find or create the following key in the registry:
>          32-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
>          64-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions
> 2. Create a new key (folder) under the Extensions key with the same name as the ID of your extension (for example, aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc).
> 3. In your extension key, create a property, "update_url", and set it to the value: "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" (this points to your extension's crx in the Chrome Web Store):
> 4. Launch the browser and go to chrome://extensions; you should see the extension listed.

This method does not work for me. Please help me find a solution.

**How to install Chrome extension through windows registry in Windows 8.1?**

Comment: What's wrong with the normal way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places I can think of that can go wrong with this:

1. Did you get **the correct ID for the extension**? If it's wrong then it won't install. You can confirm the ID by installing the extension manually, then go to `chrome://extensions`, go into developer mode, click on details, and it should give you the ID. You could also find the extension in the folder they are installed in but I don't recommend this way.
2. The instructions you posted are a bit misleading because **you don't actually need the quotes**. So just use `update_url` and the web address without quotes.